# Why model text is not displayed in html?

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

The problem is that the text of the model description_text is not displayed. And sorry for my english.

This is code of html

```
{% for description_text in context_object_name %}
     <h1 class="description"><a href="/Homepage/{{ goods.id }}/">{{goods.description_text}}</a></h1>
  {% endfor %}
```

This is code of views.py

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
model = Goods

context_object_name = 'goods.description_text'

def description(self):

    return self.description_text

def price(self):
    return self.price_text



def get_queryset(self):
    """Return the last five published questions."""
    return Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

And this is code of models.py

```
class Goods(models.Model):
description_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
price_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)



def __str__(self):
    return self.description_text

def __str__(self):
    return self.price_text
```

This is code of admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Good
from .models import Question

admin.site.register(Good)

admin.site.register(Question)


class Good(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['description_text']}),
        (None, {'fields': ['price_text']}),
    ]
```

Comment: Hi Licrencie welcome to the forum you should consider these code errors
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFfNm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFfNm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `context_object_name` is the name of the template variable used to pass the list to. Such variable names are not supposed to have a dot (`.`). You can for example use:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'Homepage/index.html'
    model = Goods
    context_object_name = 'goods'
```

In the template, you then enumerate over the `goods` and render the `description_text` for each `good`:

```
{% for good in goods %}
     <h1 class="description"><a href="/Homepage/{{ good.id }}/">{{ good.description_text }}</a></h1>
{% endfor %}
```

Your `ModelAdmin` you construct is *not* registered. Indeed, you registered the `Good` model, but not with that `ModelAdmin`, you need to define the `ModelAdmin` and link it to the `Good` model with:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Goods, Question

class GoodAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ['description_text', 'price_text']}),
    ]

# link Goods to the GoodAdmin
admin.site.register(Goods, GoodAdmin)
admin.site.register(Question)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it doesn't work

Comment: @Licrencie: the `get_queryset` method in the `IndexView` makes no sense (as well as the other methods), especially since `get_queryset` returns objects of a *different* model. Did you remove these?